# How to set property of one bean to another bean if it is in another configuration without autowire?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

With the help of `@Autowire`, it is possible to set properties from beans in another configuration.

Is it possible to do equivalent assignment in Java-based config code?

The sample is below.

It outputs:

```
instance1.instance2 = com.inthemoon.snippets.springframework.InterconfigSettingTry$Bean2@574b560f
instance1.instance3 = null
```

which proves, that property is autowired between configs.

The sample contains comments, explaining, where I would like to assign property instead of `@Autowired`:

```
public class InterconfigSettingTry {


   // first bean class with two properties, one of which is set with autowire, while another does not
   public static class Bean1 {

      @Autowired
      public Bean2 instance2;

      // @Autowired // not using autowire feature
      public Bean2 instance3;

   }

   // second bean class, which will be instantiated in two beans
   public static class Bean2 {
   }

   // java based configuration #1, which contains a bean, wishing to be aware of two beans in another config
   @Configuration
   public static class _Config1 {

      @Bean
      public Bean1 instance1() {

         Bean1 ans = new Bean1();

         // how to set ans.instance3 here without autowire?
         //ans.instance3 = ???

         return ans;
      }


   }

   // java based configuration #2
   @Configuration
   public static class _Config2 {
      @Bean
      public Bean2 instance2() {
         return new Bean2();
      }

      @Bean
      public Bean2 instance3() {
         return new Bean2();
      }
   }

   // main method 
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(_Config1.class, _Config2.class);

      Bean1 instance1 = (Bean1) context.getBean("instance1");

      System.out.println("instance1.instance2 = " + instance1.instance2);
      System.out.println("instance1.instance3 = " + instance1.instance3);

   }

}
```

Comment: Ever heard of a setter method... Create one, call it in your definition of the bean1... But if they are aware then why separate the config or not use auto config?

Comment: Please, suggest setter method, which can solve the task. Separate config is a prerequisite.

Comment: Then still I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use `@Autowired` what is the issue with that? Next to that if those are required dependencies I would use constructor injection instead of field with a setter. In your current approach you are able to create an invalid instance of `Bean1`.

Comment: I want to learn, what else can be done from Java config

Comment: Validness depends on contract. Code above is just a demonstration. I am seeking a way to create test aware beans.

Comment: Inject the other configuration into the one containing `Bean1` create a setter on `Bean1` for instance3 and just call that in the `@Bean` method that is constructing bean1. You can do everything you like in java config because it just is that, java...

Comment: I can't set the property of `instance1` to `instance3` because `instance3` doesn't exist when in `instance1()` method. See the comment in code please.

Comment: Please read my comment... You need to inject the configuration that contains `instance3` into the one that contains `instance1`. Else you need to still `@Autowire` instance3 into the configuration of `instance1`.

Comment: How to inject a configuration?

Comment: Just like any other bean]

Comment: Can you provide any example? I didn't knew configuration class is a bean. I was thinking is it instrumented inside Spring and probably never instantiated.

Comment: `@Configuration` is a `@Component` and hence is just a regular bean (with some magic applied but still a bean). You put a field in your class and slap `@Autowired` on it.

Comment: Thank you! http://imgur.com/jQilnHc